# "no such table exception" Returned on Android using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

in my app i use Using an existing sqlite database and i need to list out all records of the tables in the database. i have six tables in it.

my sqlite database file name is : **festival.sqlite** which stored in my **assets folder**.

for copying and list out the records i use the following code. but i get no such table exception while running this code. i know in the sqlite file have tables.

how to get records from tables. please help me.
my code:

```
public class main extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.sql.test/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "festival";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext;

public main(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
        Log.e("database", "database exist");
    }else{
        Log.e("database","not exist");
        this.getReadableDatabase().close();
        try {
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //throw new Error("Error copying database");
            Log.e("exception-1",e.getMessage());
            Log.e("exception-1", "Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[618496];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    myDataBase.setVersion(1);
    myDataBase.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    myDataBase.setLockingEnabled(true);
    try{
        Cursor cx = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM events"  , null);
        if (cx != null ) {
            if  (cx.moveToFirst()) {
              do {
                Log.e("ID",String.valueOf(cx.getInt(0)));
              }while (cx.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    myDataBase.close(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("exception-table", e.getMessage());
    }


}
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}    
}
```

in another activity i call the following methods:

```
             main myDbHelper = new main(this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("ex-2",ioe.getMessage());
     // throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }


    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
     // throw sqle;
    Log.e("exception",sqle.getMessage());   
    }
```

my log cat:

```
07-25 10:33:30.748: ERROR/Database(823): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.sql.test/databases/festival", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
07-25 10:33:30.748: ERROR/database(823): not exist
07-25 10:33:30.917: ERROR/exception-1(823): festival
07-25 10:33:30.917: ERROR/exception-1(823): Error copying database
07-25 10:33:30.998: ERROR/exception-table(823): no such table: events: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM events
```

Comment: have you added android_metadata table in your database before using it on android code?

Comment: i made all changes in my code like create meta_data table and as in http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-1/ . but i get same error please see my log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have not added android_metadata table then just add this and complie it will work.

for more information this is very good tutorial

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: i made all changes in my code like create meta_data table and as in http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-1/ . but i get same error please see my log cat

Comment: now just do one thing go to DDMS, inside your application folder delete festival.sqlite and copy there your new festival.sqlite(with metadata table).           or just change name to festival1.sqlite in assets folder and complie.it will work

Answer (score 0):

see the following link to copy database from assets. Also check for the table name with case sencitive

http://huuah.com/using-sqlite-from-your-android-app/
or

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-1/

Comment: i made all changes in my code like create meta_data table and as in http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-1/ . but i get same error please see my log cat